# aticonfig detects all graphics cards, but amdcccle shows the cards as disabled

Tags: 14.04, ati

I been having the strangest problem since few days ago. I have 3 ATI graphics cards and the `aticonfig --list-adapter` shows the following output

```
* 0. 01:00.0 AMD Radeon HD 7900 Series
  1. 02:00.0 AMD Radeon HD 7900 Series 
  2. 05:00.0 AMD Radeon HD 7900 Series
```

when i do `aticonfig --adapter=all --initial -f` it generates the correct X config also.

but after rebooting the output only show on primary monitor and when i look in `amdcccle` it shows the other 2 adapters as disabled. I tried with monitors attached and dummy plugs both but the situation doesn't change.

Any idea whats causing this?

also right clicking and making the adapter enabled in amdcccle and saving changes causes the X config to only have the adapter section and no screen section. after reboot the situation stays the same.

also if i look in the x.log i see the fglrx was only loaded by the first device, it does not show any error or failing on the other two devices.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

After each reboot I had a system problem dialog come up.
I reinstalled (without deleting anything) the driver not the latest one but 14.501, with --force option

`sudo sh <filename.run> --force`

I chose the generic option from the installer

after a reboot amdcccle lets me enable my cards,
after another reboot the cards stay enabled

hope this helps

ubuntu 14.04 .62